# The politics of the US presidential pardon in 2018

Tags: united-states, president, pardon

As is well known, Trump and his political and campaigning team are under investigation by the FBI. Dozens of people have been indicted so far and five have pled guilty. As the investigation continues, one of the big questions is whether anyone will testify that Trump has committed a crime and/or colluded with the Russians.

Surrounding all this is Trump’s power to pardon whoever he wants at any time.  In particular, Manafort for example is accused in the press of lying to the FBI in order to secure a pardon from Trump. In general, if Trump is guilty, anyone interviewed by the FBI who themselves has committed a crime is highly incentivised to lie knowing if they testify against Trump he will not pardon them.

In this context, it is mystifying at least to me why the US population supports the President’s pardon powers in cases that involve the President themself being investigated.  This seems to be an obvious route to corruption at the highest level. It also would not be the first time a US president has been found to be corrupt.

Given all this, what is the politics that makes the US population support this ongoing power for the President?

Comment: Note that the President can only pardon federal crimes.

Comment: Question is filled with opinion and false innuendo.  There is speculation but it is not a fact that the president is under investigation for any crime. Collusion even if true is not a crime. There is talk about obstruction of justice but that has actually not been investigated at all. All the indictments are for process crimes, none involve the president nor is it true that Manafort plead guilty to lying to protect the president. He plead guilty to a fact that Mueller already knew about, So voting to close as opinion based

Comment: @Frank Cedneno - The QUESTION (stated in the last paragraph) contains no opinion or false innuendo. The discussion leading up to the question may be provocative, but the question itself is not.

Comment: I think you need to support your claim that the US population (or a majority thereof) would in fact support pardons if the President granting them was obviously using them to shield himself from criminal investigation.  The power of the pardon is defined by the Constitution, which most support, but AFAIK the authors did not envision a President using it to shield himself, and AFAIK no President (not even Nixon) ever has.  My own opinion is that if Trump actually did so, there'd be a swift call to amend the Constitution.

Comment: @jamesqf You are right I don’t have a poll to quote. But my question was more why there isn’t a general uproar about these powers being available to Trump.  There is plenty of suggestion that these powers are *currently* influencing the Mueller investigation.

Comment: @FrankCedeno  How is lying to an FBI agent or Congress a process crime? There have also been convictions for conspiracy, financial crimes and identity theft. None of those are process crimes.

Comment: @Anush: My guess is that there's no uproar because Trump hasn't yet used the pardon to shield himself, so it's still a hypothetical question.  And in a larger context, the power does serve the useful purpose of correcting miscarriages of justice, when used responsibly.

Comment: @ jamesqf "miscarriages of justice" are to be addressed by appellate courts (at least that's the rule of law). What you are suggesting is that the President is empowered to (pardon the expression) "trump" the judiciary. Hardly the concept of 'co-equal' branches of government.

Comment: @jamesqf That's interesting. I was assuming everyone could see that the possibility of pardon has already potentially perverted the legal process by incentivising people to lie. That is he didn't actually have to use it, he just has to suggest he might.

Comment: @BobE: Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting.  First, remember that the authors of the Constitution had considerable experience with the misuse of the legal system by the British government.  As for appellate courts, sometimes they simply refuse to hear appeals despite evidence.  (I think they care a lot more about process than evidence, but IANAL.) And finally, someone might in fact be legally guilty, but morally justified.

Comment: @Anush: I can't see that the possibility of a Presidential pardon has motivated people to lie.  These people work with Trump: they can hardly have escaped knowing that he's utterly self-centered, and so would grant a pardon only if it is to his own benefit.  I imagine his lawyers have convinced him that granting pardons would create an even greater appearance of guilt on his part.

Comment: @Jamesqf - Trump has pardoned 8 persons thus far, it's not obvious he did so "to his own benefit".  Also keep in mind that when a person receives a pardon, that person can NOT utilize 5th amendment rights (self-incrimination), potentially exposing themselves and others in criminal activity.  My comment of the myth of co-equal branches still stands.

Comment: @BobE I wasn’t referring to the people he has actually pardoned, although I don’t know how popular those decisions were. But rather the effect of his pardon power on the Mueller investigation.

Comment: @jamesqf Then what on Earth is going on with Manafort, for example?  Why would he lie to the FBI having *already* pled guilty if not to gain a pardon?

Comment: @Anush: Not being a mind reader, I have no idea what's going on with Manafort.  Perhaps he has unrealistic expectations, perhaps he's just the sort of person who lies out of habit, even when telling the truth would be of more benefit.

Comment: @BobE: Looking at the Wikipedia article on those pardons & commutations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_granted_executive_clemency_by_Donald_Trump  7 of the 8 (I know nothing about Rubashkin) about seem to have benefit to Trump.  Either he pleases part of his electoral base (Arpaio, the Hammonds, &c), pleases a pressure group at no cost to himself (Johnson - and what the heck is the point of pardoning a dead person?), or he gets persuaded in a meeting with an attractive (to some, anyway) woman.

Comment: @jamesqf My mind reading skills are poor too. But the incentive to lie is clear whatever is happening in Manafort's head.

Answer (score 4):

Consider why there is a pardon power. One could see it as an anachronistic holdover from feudal times, but a properly designed pardon power is a safeguard against situations where the letter of the law fails a specific accused.

- It could be that the accused is technically guilty, but the law gives disproportionate minimum sentences. One example would be cancer patients in chronic pain who buy large quantities of illegal drugs. They are not dealers, but the law sends them behind bars for decades.
- It could be that objectively there is doubt about the guilt, but for technical reasons no appeal is possible. An example would be if DNA evidence pointing to a new suspect shows up after all appeals for the trial are exhausted.

To become such a last resort, pardon powers have to be sweeping. The safeguard is political scrutiny on the few senior officials who have this power. (Who that is differs. In the UK it is technically still the queen, for instance, even if she delegates it.)

It becomes a problem when someone close to the President is accused of a crime and the **President's Party** lacks the integrity to make it crystal clear that they'd vote for impeachment if any pardons are granted. That's not a failure of the pardon process, it is a failure of the political process as a whole.

Comment: There are no pardons in the UK as far as I know.

Comment: @Anush, not commonly used but still there.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I still don’t understand why people would allow the president to pardon people he is in a conspiracy with. This seems a fundamental flaw in the constitution that is easily remedied by removing pardon powers for those investigated by a special counsel, for example.

Comment: @Anush, imagine a situation where members of the government or armed forces did something under orders which the President cannot *officially* [admit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Contra_affair#Pardons). Say meddling with the politics of a nominally friendly country or breaking domestic law for foreign policy reasons. If they are pardoned, everyone would guess they were acting under orders, but people could *pretend* that it was a rogue operation and not official government policy. Such polite fictions can be helpful in diplomacy.

Comment: That seems a niche and not necessarily desirable reason to award so much unfettered power. At least IMHO.

Comment: This answer continues the false opinionated question. A sitting president cannot be prosecuted for any crime no matter how compelling the proof. there exists no criminal court that has jurisdiction over a sitting president.  It is for Congress to sit in judgement over the president. Congress isn't a criminal court nor does it need a violation of law to prosecute. Congress can impeach/convict a President for anything they want. Finally the Mueller investigation is not to find if the president committed a crime, it is to find if there was Russian interference or a failure to protect elections

Comment: @FrankCedeno, I understood the question was not about US Constitutional law **as it is today** but about why it should be as it is today. And surely you agree that there could have been a constitution without the pardon power, or without presidential immunity (even if the latter brings separation-of-powers concerns).

Comment: @Anush: The US Constitution is not easily changed.  It takes either a Constitutional Convention (which has never happened since the first), or a 2/3 majority of both houses of Congress, then ratification by the legislatures of 3/4 of the states.  This can take quite some time.  (The 27th Amendment took a bit over 200 years to be ratified :-))  It'd be much easier just to impeach & convict a President who misuses the power.

Comment: @FrankCedeno That’s not really true. Point 1 of Mueller’s instructions are to investigate any links and/or coordination between the Russian government and individuals associated with the campaign of President Donald Trump.

Comment: @FrankCedeno As to prosecuting a sitting President, I understand it’s likely (but not certain) this is not possible but he can be impeached and then prosecuted. Moreover he can be impeached *because* there is evidence to prosecute him.

Comment: @jamesqf So do you feel the population largely don’t even think about constitutional changes, no matter how desirable, just because they are so hard to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

[The US Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardon#U.S._Constitution) (generally supported by the US population) states (boldface added):

> The President shall be Commander in Chief of the Army and Navy of the United States,...  and he **shall have Power** to grant Reprieves and Pardons for Offenses against the United States, **except in Cases of Impeachment**.

That is the simplest and straight-forward answer to your question.

As you did NOT ask why this is in the US Constitution, there is no reason to try to speculate on the "why".

(Boldface emphasis added by user agc; not in original document)

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, I thought he asked exactly that.

Comment: My question is why there isn’t a popular move to amend the constitution, given the obvious conflict it brings for the Mueller investigation.

Comment: @anush -Respectfully, the only sentence that ends with a question mark is your last sentence. You presented no question about a popular move to amend. Furthermore a question of such nature is soliciting rank speculation, and as such,  is off-topic.

Comment: @BobE Surprisingly, I agree :)